# Does Openstack Swift Object server know quorum configuration?

Tags: openstack-swift, cloud-storage

Appreciate your help to clarify some doubts regarding Openstack swift Quorums.
1) Who actually knows the quorum configurations? Is it proxy or Storage server?
2) When the proxy sends the request to the object server, does that request include the quorum configuration for the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy node has a copy of the object ring which controls the storage locations for the replicas (and all of the handoff locations in case the primary locations are unavailable).  Quorum is determined by the proxy node when it receives enough success responses from the storage node to make a quorum (e.g. 2 if replica count is 3).  The storage node does not need to understand a quorum.